# Office js multi page Add-ins Navigation

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I recently started working on an Add-in for Microsoft Excel. I am new to node js.  The documentation and online tutorials are well and good for a single page add-in, but I could not find any help for an Add-in that has multiple pages and user can navigate to those pages.

I have tried multiple ways, with express routes, it does not render the page,

Although each file contains Office.OnReady call as mentioned in tutorials.

I know I am doing something wrong here but cannot put my finger on it. Any help regarding this would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Edit : 
location.href do work, but is it a good practice to use it for  navigation?

Here is js code:

```js
   Office.onReady(info => {
  if (info.host === Office.HostType.Excel) {

    // Determine if the user's version of Office supports all the Office.js APIs that are used in the tutorial.
    if (!Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('ExcelApi', '1.7')) {
      console.log('Sorry. The tutorial add-in uses Excel.js APIs that are not available in your version of Office.');
    }

    // Assign event handlers and other initialization logic.
    document.getElementById("app-body").style.display = "flex",
    document.getElementById("login").onclick = authenticate
  }
});

function get_user_input() {
  var platform_url = document.getElementById("platform-url").value
  var username = document.getElementById("username").value
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value

  return [platform_url, username, password]
}

function authenticate(request, response) {
  var input = get_user_input()

  // perform authentication logic here

  window.location.href = "https://localhost:3000/index.html";
}
```

And here is the related HTML from where call is being made

```
<!-- Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. Licensed under the MIT License. -->
<!-- This file shows how to design a first-run page that provides a welcome screen to the user about the features of the add-in. -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Exceljs</title>

    <!-- Office JavaScript API -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js"></script>

    <!-- For more information on Office UI Fabric, visit https://developer.microsoft.com/fabric. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-core/9.6.1/css/fabric.min.css" />

    <!-- Template styles -->
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body class="ms-font-m ms-welcome ms-Fabric">
    <header class="ms-welcome__header ms-bgColor-neutralLighter">
        <img width="90" height="90" src="../../assets/logo.png" alt="logo" title="logo" />
    </header>
    <main id="app-body" class="ms-welcome__main" style="display: none;">
        <!-- URL section -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Platform URL:</label>
            <input type="text" id="platform-url" value="" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" value="" />
        </div>
        <!-- Button -->
        <div class="form-action">
            <button class="ms-Button" id="login">Login</button><br/><br/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label class="error-banner" id="error-banner"></label>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does an ordinary <A ...> link to one of your other pages work? Also, can you show the part of the JavaScript where you call `onReady` and the part of the HTML page where you load that JavaScript file?

Comment: I have edited the initial problem. location.href works, but I am wondering if it is the best solution?

Comment: Yes. It is fine to use the location object in an add-in.

Comment: how about routing using express or angular? is that achievable in add-ins.

Comment: Yes. You can use express or angular in add-ins.